# How to create custom validation from react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to create a custom validation starting from the validation below. But I'm not successful so far. I had visited [this site](https://www.carlrippon.com/custom-validation-rules-in-react-hook-form/) and followed the codes in his "Custom validation rules" but I can't replicate it.

The `isBefore` method is working fine, but the validation does not. And also how can we put a custom message with this custom validation?

```
const isBefore = (date1, date2) => moment(date1).isBefore(moment(date2));

const rules = {
    publishedDate: {
        required: 'The published date is required.',
        before: isBefore(scheduledDate, expiredDate)
    },
}

<Controller
    control={control}
    name="publishedDate"
    rules={rules.publishedDate}
    render={({ onChange }) => (
        <DatePicker
            className="mb-px-8"
            onChange={(value) => {
                setPublishedDate(value);
                onChange(value);
            }}
            minDate={new Date()}
            value={publishedDate}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

you need to use the hook useEffect and a controller.
at the top of the page you need these two imports:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
```

then you need the validation function this lives outside of the component.

```
const isBefore = (date) => {
  if (!date) {
    return false;
  }
  const today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return date > today;
};
```

The above function checks that the date you picked is in the future and not the past.

Under your component you set everything to useForm

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    setValue,
    watch,
    errors,
    setError,
    clearError
  } = useForm();
```

You then setup variables to watch for the datepicker to update, along with useEffect to watch for the change:

```
  const startDate = watch("startDate");
  useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "startDate", type: "custom" }, { validate: { isBefore } });
  });
```

You then define a handler inside of the component that handles the data change along with the validation.

```
  const handleDateChange = (dateType) => (date) => {
    if (!isBefore(date)) {
      setError(dateType, "isBefore");
    } else {
      setError(dateType, "isBefore");
    }
    setValue(dateType, date);
    alert(date);
  };
```

the custom error message can exist anywhere in the form and you don't need to tie a ref to it. the useForm() and watch('startDate') control the data for you.

Here is the custom error message that can live anywhere within the form component.

**Please see updated codesandbox where I have the custom error message displayed near the submit button**

```
              {errors.startDate && (
                <div variant="danger">
                  {errors.startDate.type === "isBefore" && (
                  <p>Please choose present or future date!</p>
                  )}
                </div>
```

Here is a working codesandbox that I cleaned up a bit from yesterday, and added in some comments.
https://codesandbox.io/s/play-momentjs-forked-1hu4s?file=/src/index.js:1494-1802

If you click the input and then choose a date in the past, and then click submit, the custom error message will show. However, if you select a date in the future and hit submit the message doesn't show.

Here is a resource I used:
https://eincode.com/blogs/learn-how-to-validate-custom-input-components-with-react-hook-form

Also more information on watch that you get from useForm function:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/

Answer (score 7):

Try using **rules** of react-hook-form to add validations

```
  <Controller
    name="currentName"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <TextField
        value={field.value}
        onChange={field.onChange}
        inputRef={field.ref}
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        fullWidth
        autoComplete="off"
        helperText={helperText}
      />
    )}
    rules={{
      validate: {
        required: (value) => {
          if (value === "SomeValue") return 'Some Message';
          if (!value) return '*Required';
        }
      },
      maxLength: 5
    }}
    defaultValue=""
  />
```